# extracting cloudformation template from an existing instances of AWS services (e.g. a dynamodb table)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, devops, infrastructure

I am exploring infrastructure as code ....

I have built a small application using AWS serives  based around dynamo,  and Lamdha functions. Is there a way to extract (download) the cloudformation templates that would  described these resources (I created them by hand the first time) so I can automate the duplication of these into a different region (for example), or tear down and rebuild within the same region?

thanks!

Comment: If you are going to use DynamoDB and Lambda functions, you should also have a look at AWS SAM to keep your templates cleaner and smaller. I doubt a tool will exist that is able to create a SAM template for you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best tool for that would be fully open-source tool called [former2](https://github.com/iann0036/former2) developed an [AWS Hero](https://aws.amazon.com/developer/community/heroes/ian-mckay/):

> Generate CloudFormation / Terraform / Troposphere templates from your existing AWS resources